# nginx index.html does not update after modification

Tags: nginx

Sorry for noob question, I suck at Ubuntu.

I have just installed nginx in a Ubuntu server with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install nginx
```

It successfully built. I'm trying to change the index page, so I have modified my `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`, and then tried all of these:

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service nginx start
sudo service nginx restart
```

But when I refresh the root page on my browser it still shows the old page.

This is what the index.html looks like:
[image]

I have checked my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, but don't find anything particular there.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 7):

If you had checked vhost, you knowned, root directory is /var/www/html...

vhost is in /etc/nginx/sites-available and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled (sites-enabled is symlink).

Comment: sorry what is vhost?

Comment: It's a configuration file. If you inspect your configuration file (should be `default`), you should see a line that reads `root ...`. The `root` directive tells you which directory NGINX is serving the content out of (in your case). In other words, the file you want to modify is `/var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html` and not the one in the share folder.

Comment: That solved it. So which of the two links that @przemyslawJagielski suggested are the configurartion file? I'm having another problem with another redirect and I think that's the problem. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The correct configuration file for NGINX on Debian is :

```
/var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html
```

If you update this file, the changes will be reflected immediately, without a start/stop or restart.

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service nginx start
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html is not a configuration file, it's a html file

Answer (score 0):

Build image:

```
 docker build -t imagename .
```

Detach image from localhost upstream and sync to container:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:80 --name containername imagename
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  5;
error_log  /etc/nginx/errors.log;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
 upstream client {
     server localhost:5000;
 }

 server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location /{
        proxy_pass http://4a425c847f78:5000;
     }
  }
 }
```

Image Id :

```
 4a425c847f78
```

Forever stop ~/app/app.js :

```
forever stopall
```

Run app.js with port 80:

```
node app.js
```

Forever start ~/app/app.js with port 3000:

```
forever start app.js
```

Start Docker:

```
docker stop imagename
docker start imagename
```

Start nginx:

```
systemctl stop nginx
systemctl start nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your app like below

```
sudo systemctl restart app
```

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem before, then after updating nginx conf by moving 'root' from 'server/location' to 'server', it works well. Nginx config file :

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/rdist;

    location /user/ {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:9191;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:9191;
    }
    location /auth/ {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:9191;
    }


    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        if (!-e $request_filename){
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
        }
    }
```